# Flag for moderator attention on review page.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flagging

The [review page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review) does have a “flag for attention” link, but clicking the link seems to immediately flag the post without possibility to choose a reason. It would be nicer if the usual dialog with the choice of different flags pops up.

Comment: I didn't even know this page. I wonder how many pages I still miss. It took me a while to even find pages like "favorites" here. It there a site map or something?

Comment: @Martin: None that I know. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange is pretty useful to keep up-to-date with new features.

Comment: @Caramdir. Perhaps you can give us a clue on how you found it?

Comment: @Martin: A clue to find the 'favorites' page would also be nice!

Comment: @Joseph: The review page? From the link above: “*2010-12-16: new /review page on all sites (eg. SO, math) for tracking potential problem posts from new users. This uses some heuristics for detecting a bad answer.*” Also, the suggested edits list (which only pops up for 10k users when there are suggested edits) links to that page.

Comment: @Caramdir: I meant 'where the **** is the link to the Review page?' I can't see one at all!

Comment: @Joseph: Favorites is on your profile page (there are several links below the biography field).

Comment: @Joseph: I was talking about your own favorites, the posts you marked with a star. Go to your user page, i.e. click on your name on top, then on "favorites" just below the "about me" text on the right. These are: *stats activity reputation favorites prefs accounts*.

Comment: @Joseph: Except for the suggested edits link that is sometimes visible, there is none.

Comment: @Caramdir. I know about that one, but it's always seemed a bit pointless. I'd naïvely assumed that there would be a 'favourites' link on the main site page.

Comment: I also found http://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation useful to see a complete list of your reputation. It is a simple database dump.

Comment: Thanks both for the clarification: perhaps it's just me ...

Comment: @Martin. Wow, how did you find that?

Comment: Btw, there is also [the reputation page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation), but I think they keep that hidden because rep recalcs are fairly computation intensive.

Comment: @Joseph: again from the recent changes list

Comment: @Joseph: I was googling about reputation on SO sites and there was a SO question which explained it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this was posted the review page has changed a lot. In any case the flag links on the review page now works as expected.